# How to user AJAX response using only HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to use AJAX and Javascript (no jQuery) to update a DIV on my page to display an AJAX request based off of the user submitted response.

I have two questions.

1) How can I alter the AJAX request based off the user submitted response? I would also like to store the response for other AJAX requests on the same page as well. The below code does not seem to return anything to my browser and is not updating the DIV.

```
function loadXMLDoc(){
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(),
        userReq = documents.forms["form"]["req"].value;
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
            document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","ajaxRequest" + "userReq",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

2) The AJAX request I'm using returns a JSON object. How do I use Javascript to modify and only display particular values of the returned JSON?

i.e The following JSON is returned from an AJAX call, only update the DIV to show Anna's last name, "Smith".

```
{"employees":[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
]}
```

Comment: You should parse the JSON String to a JSON Object with "var myJSON = JSON.parse(jsonString);" and then access to the object, for example, "myJSON.employees[1].lastName" should use Anna's last name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ad 1) `userReq` is a variable containing a value, if you use it as `"userReq"` you will get the literal string "userReq" rather than the value of the variable `userReq`

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajaxRequest?userReq=" + userReq,true);
```

This will allow your server side script to receive the value of `userReq` in the request variable named `"userReq"`

ad 2) JSON is the Javascript object notation, so using JSON in Javascript is quite easy

```
var myObject = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);

// get only Anna's last name
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = myObject.employees[1].lastName;
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. But I'm still a little confused with #2. If I want my div to update to the parsed JSON, how would I input that in my loadXmlDoc function? The function is currently displaying the full xmlhttp.responseText.